# Range input ng-model problems when max is set dinamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, forms

I have noticed that my range input no longer has its value initialized by `ng-model` once I started to set the `max` value dynamically.

This is my input:

```
<input name="age" type="range" class="" min="1" step="1"
    max="{{ageLabelList.length}}"
    ng-model="age" />
```

I have checked my variables with console, and age is outputting correctly as `3`, and ageLabelList.length is outputting correctly as `4`, but my range still points at `1` as I load my page. If I set the `max` value manually as `4`, everything works fine.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with setting max with angulars as I check on angular version 1.4.8 (check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ehsabd/5no99xep/). You've probably made a typo mistake or something or maybe that's related to your angular version. Can you provide your full code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it seems that it works well, even on the version `angularjs 1.2.1`

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/5no99xep/2/)